# Необходимо сохранить статистику из 'test.log' в Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

День вечер!
Если коротко о тз то необходимо :

1. распаковать(запомнить имя архива), 2. парсить(получить строки). 3 создать таблицу в POSTRGESQL, где: 1) - колонка testid - имя архива (без tar.gz) 2) - далее названия колонок в файле 'columns.csv' (121 имя ) 4. Записать распарсенные данные в таблицу.

Ссылка на архив и таблицу
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t0tIVOMI36i6kl0ByPr4gxddUEC0h9lQ

/Пример строки/ -

```
3;fio-3.27-12-gd7a2;oltp_read_uniform;0;0;66362840;553019;69127;120001;3;662;7.105567;0.883065;17;23249;107.165068;60.988828;1.000000%=62;5.000000%=86;10.000000%=89;20.000000%=92;30.000000%=95;40.000000%=97;50.000000%=99;60.000000%=101;70.000000%=104;80.000000%=109;90.000000%=119;95.000000%=164;99.000000%=197;99.500000%=242;99.900000%=954;99.950000%=970;99.990000%=1613;0%=0;0%=0;0%=0;50;23256;114.506388;60.999852;489672;621288;100.000000%;553040.327731;1646.634228;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.000000;0.000000;0;0;0.000000;0.000000;1.000000%=0;5.000000%=0;10.000000%=0;20.000000%=0;30.000000%=0;40.000000%=0;50.000000%=0;60.000000%=0;70.000000%=0;80.000000%=0;90.000000%=0;95.000000%=0;99.000000%=0;99.500000%=0;99.900000%=0;99.950000%=0;99.990000%=0;0%=0;0%=0;0%=0;0;0;0.000000;0.000000;0;0;0.000000%;0.000000;0.000000;2.976875%;9.288333%;8295390;0;381;100.0%;0.0%;0.0%;0.0%;0.0%;0.0%;0.0%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.01%;0.01%;50.52%;49.00%;0.24%;0.01%;0.19%;0.03%;0.01%;0.01%;0.01%;0.01%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%;0.00%
```

Comment: а откуда известно, что именно эта строка - нужная? А не предыдущая и не следующая или не еще какая-нибудь

Comment: опять 25. что достать нужно? саму строку из файла? тогда причем здесь регулярки? или из этой строки достать что-то нужно?

Comment: Можно тупо бить строки через `split(';')`, проверять, достаточно ли получилось элементов в строке и потом сравнивать нужные элементы с искомыми.

Comment: @strawdog из этой стоки всё нужно достать , все значения . начиная от 3;  и до 0.00% .

test.log файл огромный , и  в нем много всего не нужного , данные которые нужны   именно для БД пишутся лишь в этой маленькой строчке.

Comment: @strawdog можно с вами  связаться ?

Comment: В приведенном в ссылке файле я вижу три строки с похожим форматом. нужно вытащить все три? или только первую строку после `Starting 24 processes`?

Comment: @strawdog секунду , сейчас разберусь и отвечу

Comment: @strawdog "все три, их в принципе сколько угодно может быть" ответ от руководителя.  Я так понимаю что это  просто как запуск разных тестов идет. В этом логе их было запущено три теста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принципиально сделать можно таким образом:

```
lst=[]
with open('test.log', 'r') as f:
    while "Starting" not in f.readline():
        pass
    while True :
        s = f.readline()
        print(s)
        if "{" in s:
            break
        else:
            lst.append(s.strip())
        
res = [x.split(';') for x in lst]
```

теперь в `res`у вас список списков с нужными строками, разбитыми по ';'.

Comment: Так то, да. КоТэ работает... Вот только я по прежнему думаю, что Александре нужно  ознакомить сообщество с полным заданием... а так то одно парсим
, то другое... в итоге по прежнему не очевидно, что именно нужно.

Comment: «Без внятного ТЗ, результат хз», Я пыталась..

Comment: Сейчас думаю ,что уже можно этот результат  в попытаться бд сложить

Comment: Спасибо , за помощь)

Comment: Сам лог содержит дублированную информацию. То есть полученные данные в res (121 значение для каждой из трех строк) содержится в структурированных данных ниже по файлу лога. Сама структура гораздо богаче... ОТСЮДА!
Сама постановка вопроса "как положить строку в POSTRGESQL?" - сомнительна.

Comment: Как тогда ещё можно понять это тз ( необходимо сохранить статистику из 'test.log' в Postgres.

Программа должна распаковывать архив, как в приложенном примере, находить 'test.log' и парсить его.
При парсинге надо - найти строки в csv формате и вставить в таблицу.

Название колонок:
1) testid - имя архива (без tar.gz)
2) и далее в файле 'columns.csv'

Comment: Ну так вот именно вот так и нужно было вопрос задать... )

Comment: Отлично! Вот именно так вопрос задайте! И положите на гугл диск архив. И пример. Потому что нужно не только парсить... 1. распаковать(запомнить имя архива), 2. парсить(получить строки). 3 создать таблицу в POSTRGESQL, где:
   1) - колонка testid - имя архива (без tar.gz) 2) - далее названия колонок в файле 'columns.csv' 
  (121 имя )
4. Записать распарсенные данные в таблицу.

Comment: ошибка 130 имен столбцов

Comment: @A_Vaclav подправила вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129107/discussion-between-a-vaclav-and--).

Answer (score 1):

пока два шага

```
#######################
#     STEP 1
#######################
import tarfile

name_tar = "fio-example (3).tar.gz"
tar = tarfile.open(name_tar)
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
#распакует весь архив, то есть путь будет ..\fio-example\test.log
##############################
#      STEP 2
##############################
import re
import json
import os

dir_t = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir_t, 'fio-example', 'test.log')

def reader(filename):

    regexp = r'{(?s:.*)}'

    with open(filename) as f:
        log = f.read()

       json_value = re.findall(regexp, log)

       log_dict = json.loads(json_value[0])

       print(log_dict["fio version"])#проверочный

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader(filename)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, улучшите код. Распаковка всего архива - НЕ ОПТИМАЛЬНО.
Я не разобрался, как достать файл из подкаталога...
Пока что видится вариант с копированием файла и удалением подкаталога ... но это не точно. ))