# Парсинг файла. Не могу найти ошибку в коде Python

Tags: python, парсер, логирование, ос, tar

Подскажите пожалуйста ,вот пишу я парсер , но что-то код никак не запускается, не могу понять в чем ошибка (

ссылка на tar https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IcMbzGRFlhlzzPQKIWIxJGZOVQr2vXsf

```
import tarfile
import os


name_tar = input('Введите имя tar-архива ,который необходимо распаковать : ')# fio-example.tar.gz
log_file = input('Введите имя log файла : ') #test.log

def reader(name_tar,log_file):
    
    try:
        tar = tarfile.open(name_tar)
    except:
        print('Файл ' + name_tar + ' отсутствует!')
    tar.extractall()#извлечь всё
    tar.close()

    #распакует весь архив, то есть путь будет ..\fio-example\test.log
    dir_t = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    log_file_path = os.path.join(dir_t, 'fio-example', log_file)

    try:
        f = open(log_file_path,"r")
    except:
        print('Файл ' + log_file_path + ' отсутствует!')
    

#Чтение строк лог файла
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    lst = []
    marker = 0 #Находим маркеры начала и конца блока, который вырезаем из лог файла
    for s in lines:
            if ("Starting" in s) or ("{" in s):
                marker+=1
            if (marker==2):
                break
            if (marker==1) and ("Starting" not in s):
                lst.append(s.strip())
                print(lst)
    return lst

parsed_lst= reader(log_file,name_tar)
```

Comment: даже не пишет "Введите имя tar-архива ,который необходимо распаковать :"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление функции:

```
def reader(name_tar, log_file):
```

Вызов функции:

```
parsed_lst = reader(log_file, name_tar)
```

Найди два отличия.

Comment: :-) "Шо!!! Опять!!! Мистер @Эникейщик, не ведись. Честно сказать довольно не приятно видеть, когда твой код используют в "мутных" целях. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322636/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-test-log-%D0%B2-postgres/]